# Grillet - Abstract Algebra - Second Edition, proposition 5.5 of section II.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the following proof of this proposition:

> If a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is normal in $G$, then it is the largest $p$-subgroup of $G$ and the only Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

First, some definitions:

If $p$ is a prime number, a $\mathbf{p}$**-group** is a group whose order is $p^k$, with $k\in\mathbb{N}$. A **Sylow** $\mathbf{p}$-subgroup of a finite group $G$ is a subgroup of order $p^k$ such that $p^k$ divides $|G|$ and $p^{k+1}$ does not divide $|G|$.

Going back to the statement, the proof goes like this:

> Let the Sylow $p$-subgroup $S$ be normal in $G$. If $T$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$, then $ST\leq G$ and $|ST|=|S||T|/|S\cap T|\geq |S|$, by Third Isomorphism Theorem. *(Up to this point everything is fine, since both $|S|$ and $|T|$ are powers of a prime, and $S\cap T$ is a subgroup of  $T$).*
> Hence, $|ST|=|S|$, by the choice of $S$, so that $T\subset ST=S$  (this last line is where I don't understand).

I know $ST=\langle S\cup T\rangle$ (I think Hungerford's Algebra talks about this as **join** of sets). Maybe that's useful to understand the above, but not sure.

Comment: $ST$ has the same number of elements as $S$, but contains $S$. So they are equal as sets. Since $T$ is contained in $ST$, then it is contained in $S$.

Comment: "$ST$ has the same number of elements as $S$". That's because I showed $|ST|\geq |S|$ and the other inequality $|S|\leq |ST|$ is trivial, right?

Comment: Yes, because $S\subseteq ST$.

Comment: Thank you, Arturo.

Comment: @FabrizioGambelín isn’t other inequality you wrote is same as showed inequality (order of $S$ is less than or equal to order of $ST$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, statement of proposition and its proof is bit messy. There is no need to say largest $p$-subgroup, it simply means Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. In proof part, I don’t clearly see why $|ST|=|S|$ holds.

More general definition of $p$-group is following: $G$ is said to be $p$-group if $\forall g\in G$, $|g|=p^i$ for some $i\geq 0$. When order of $G$ is finite, general definition is equivalent to $|G|$ is power of $p$. For existence of non-trivial Sylow $p$-subgroup, you only need to specify $p$ divides $|G|$. It’s easy to see that $|G|=p^km$ such that $(p,m)=1$. Then any Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ has order $p^k$.

This proposition are mostly proved using second Sylow theorem. Suppose $T$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. By second Sylow theorem, $\exists g\in G$ such that $T=gSg^{-1}$. Since $S$ is normal in $G$, we have $S=gSg^{-1}$. Thus $S=T$.